# Audio recording problem

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-audio

I am trying to use Apple's [**RecordAudioToFile**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/RecordAudioToFile/Introduction/Intro.html) and **[MyRecorder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/MYRecorder/Listings/MyRecorderController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004263-MyRecorderController_m-DontLinkElementID_15)** examples. The first example runs well and the file is recorded but I can't hear any sound. And the second example, when I press the Start button, it does nothing. I'm using a Mac Mini to record.

Comment: The Mac Mini does not have a microphone.  Can you record using other programs, like Quicktime Player?

Comment: I tried to record by Quicktime Player, but it's not working. Could you please tell me clearly?

Comment: Are you saying the recording is a flatline (no audio), or that you can't hear it while it's recording (no play-through/monitoring)? Have you plugged in a microphone or other audio source? Is it selected in the Sound prefpane?

Comment: I have plugged in a microphone and the recording is a flatline. It is selected in the Sound prefpane too.

Comment: Can you confirm that there is audio data in the file?

Comment: As [MyRecorder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/MYRecorder/Listings/MyRecorderController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004263-MyRecorderController_m-DontLinkElementID_15) example, it outputs .mov file. In this example, I debugged and it received device input is headphone (in this code _QTCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [QTCaptureDevice defaultInputDeviceWithMediaType:QTMediaTypeSound];
    success = [audioDevice open:&error];_), but it cannot output the .mov file.